# unexpected filtering results in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm having some issues with filtering data in my program.

The foll is my JSON sample:

```
    {
"expression": "to the day",
"meaning": "",
"example": "it's been four years to the day.",
"pronunciation": "",
"notes": "",
"meta": {
"book": [""],
"author": [""],
"tags": ["music"]}
},
```

The foll is a part of my filter logic:

```
<md-input-container>
<label>Enter Search Term</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="classifiedsFilter">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
<label>Tags</label>
<md-select ng-model="tag">
<md-option ng-repeat="tag in tags | orderBy: 'toString()'" value="{{ tag }}"> <!-- tags here refers to a newly defined array that stores only one instance of all the tags against the 'tags' property on each object/word -->
{{ tag }} 
</md-option>
</md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

the foll are my filters on md-card:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds | filter: classifiedsFilter | filter: tag:true | filter: expression | filter: book:true | filter: author:true | orderBy: order" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="40" flex-gt-sm="30" class="classified">
```

The problem that i am facing is as follows:

If i were to select a particular tag from the Tags dropdown. the results are narrowed down as expected; however, when i click the 'Clear' button, none of the results are displayed. I have to refresh the page for all the results to be displayed again

Can you pls help me understand where im going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: So where is the clear code?

Comment: @charlietfl: i am sorry for the delay. the foll is the code for 'Clear' button: `<md-input-container>
   <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="classifiedsFilter = ''; tag = ''; book = ''; author = ''; order = ''  ">Clear</md-button>
  </md-input-container>`